How to trace Chrome shortcut app-id to the underlying URL?
I am using Windows 10. A desktop shortcut opens a Chrome page.  When I look at the properties of the shortcut it has two relevant fields.

Start in contains  C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application
Target contains C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome_proxy.exe  --profile-directory=Default --app-id=mnldlokfggemdhdciaoebdjoncilpjac

I would like to find the URL that the app-id field eventually points to. Where is the long app-id string stored and is it inside a *.ldb or manifest file?
